# how to assign value to a get-only property

Tags: ios, swift, struct

As the movie struct shows as below, I want to upload my `vote` vault through the `upVote` function but the error occurs as "Cannot assign to property: 'vote' is a get-only property".

Except for the `vote` and 'isFavored, other properties are all decoded from a local JSON file.

**my struct**

```
struct Movie:Codable,Identifiable{
    let id=UUID()
    let MOVIE_ID:String
    let NAME:String
    let ALIAS:String
    let ACTORS:String
    let COVER:String
    let DIRECTORS:String
    let DOUBAN_SCORE:String
    let DOUBAN_VOTES:String
    let GENRES:String
    let IMDB_ID:String
    let LANGUAGES:String
    let DIRECTOR_IDS:String
\\my own property:
    var isFavered:Bool = false
\\init the vote
    var vote:Int{
        if let v = Int(DOUBAN_VOTES){
            return v
        }else{
            return 0
        }
        
    }
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case MOVIE_ID, NAME,ALIAS,ACTORS,COVER,DIRECTORS,DOUBAN_SCORE
        case DOUBAN_VOTES,GENRES,IMDB_ID,LANGUAGES,MINS,OFFICIAL_SITE
        case REGIONS,RELEASE_DATE,SLUG,STORYLINE,TAGS,YEAR,ACTOR_IDS,DIRECTOR_IDS
    }
\\my uploade vote function
    func upVote(newVote:Int){
        vote = newVote \\ here occurs the error
    }
}
```

Comment: With regard to my comment in your previous question: Now as you’ve added CodingKeys there’s no reason anymore to use the ugly UPPER_SNAKE_CASE property names 

Comment: Yes,thanks I also got the same advice from another answer I will change them once I figure how to change the value of the properties

Comment: It seems your question was answered but your response is to turn it into a totally different question?

Comment: Yes actually I started using StackOverflow weeks ago, in this case, should I open a new question?

Comment: I have rolled back the question to match what was originally asked and what has been answered. Please post a new question instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for the mistake I made when asking questions on StackOverflow, I post the new one in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69252748/value-can-not-be-changed-in-a-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.

First, as you have discovered, you can't modify `vote` because it is a [computed property](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#).  Its value is determined by the code in its getter method.  Assigning a value doesn't make sense.

I guess you have used a computed property because your JSON source is, frankly, awful.  Integers should be sent as integers, not strings.

Assuming you can't change the JSON to something more sensible, then you will just need to update the underlying `DOUBAN_VOTES` property in your `upVote` function.  You will need to make `DOUBAN_VOTES` a `var`, not a `let`.

This will reveal your second problem; Structs are immutable. In order to allow a function to change a value, it must be flagged as a `mutating` function.

```
var DOUBAN_VOTES:String

mutating func upVote(newVote: Int) {
    self.DOUBAN_VOTES = "\(newVote)"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's true that my JSON source is terrible and I'm not sure it's suitable to make my `DOUBAN_VOTES` property a var since it's read from the file. Do I need to write back to the JSON file if I change the data? Because if it's reread from the file the value would not be changed.

Comment: Writing updated data back to the server is an entirely different matter.  Yes, in a typical client/server application you would persist changes back to the server.  Assuming that is not in your scope at this time there is no problem with modifying the `DOUBAN_VOTES` property, just recognise that your changes won't be persisted and next time you fetch the data it will be the original data.  Also, since you have gone to the trouble of adding `CodingKeys` you should use them to make Swift style property names.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've changed the property name and add a new class to make other properties changeable, updating in my question. However I don't know why I can't get the value changed when I click the vote button

Comment: Where didn't the value change?  In the structure? On screen?  If you are talking about changing the value on the screen you need to write code that updates the screen when you change the value.  It won't happen automatically. Are you using UIKit or SwiftUI?

Comment: I see from your rolled-back edit you are using SwiftUI, so you need to look at using an appropriate model; An ObservableObject, for example

Answer (score 1):

You first need to declare `DOUBAN_VOTES` as mutable and then change the computed property to be mutable. By using `private(set)` for DOUBAN_VOTES it will be immutable outside of the struct.

```
private(set) var DOUBAN_VOTES: String

var vote: Int {
  get {
    return Int(DOUBAN_VOTES) ?? 0
  }
  set {
    DOUBAN_VOTES = String(newValue)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can the`DOUBAN_VOTE` remain as `let`? like pass the `newValue` to `vote` instead of `DOUBAN_VOTE`

Comment: No it must be mutable with this solution. Maybe it would be better to look for a completely different solution like creating a new struct or class for the voting so that the Movie struct is all immutable.

Comment: ok, I'll try it out, thanks again!!

Comment: hi there, I add a `myMovie` class as it shows in the question. However on the test page when I click the vote button the value didn't change.